# Having multiple foreign keys to same table with different on delete causes error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table with 2 foreign keys pointing to different users in same table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InstallerDetails]
(
    [UserId] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    [AssignedSalesman] int NULL
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(Id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    ...some more columns
)
```

`UserId` is pointing to required user, when that user is deleted, I want to delete its details as well.

`AssignedSalesman` is pointing to some other user, that is optional and I want to set null when that user is deleted.

However, this structure results in an error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__Installer__Assig__6D0D32F4' on table 'InstallerDetails' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I don't see how it could cause cycles. Is that indeed an error? Is there any other way I could achieve this kind of logic?

Comment: It feels weird that you are using UserId as a primary key and foreign key. Of course that makes it 1:1 relation, but could that be the reason? What happens if you create separate primary key column on your table.

Comment: Separating UserId to 2 fields does not change a thing, same error. I did it this way because there are many types of users that can have different sets of fields, and I want to make sure that each set of details is strongly connected to its original user.

Comment: @ex4: That's not necessarily weird. A primary key that is also a foreign key is a common concept when modelling weak entities. The only thing is that weak entities don't occur very often "in the wild" and therefore such constellation of primary and foreign keys is rarely seen in schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well known SQL Server behaviour, two or more `on delete` paths from a child to a parent are not allowed. This will run ok for example

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InstallerDetails]
(
    [UserId] int not null PRIMARY KEY foreign key references Users(Id) on delete cascade
    ,[AssignedSalesman] int null foreign key references Users(Id) 
)
```

You can enforce missing `on delete set null` with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
+-------+--------+--------------------+
| RowID | UserId | [AssignedSalesman] |
+-------+--------+--------------------+
|     1 | userA  | userB              |
|     2 | userB  | userC              |
|     3 | userC  | userD              |
+-------+--------+--------------------+
```

If you `delete .. where RowID=1`

Then suddenly all rows are empty. I guess that's what SQL Server is trying to avoid. (I'd like to be able to deactivate this check too, though).